# Prevent date selection in the past

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

How do we prevent the datepicker from picking a date in the past?

I used the following:

```
 $("#Date").datepicker({ minDate: '0' });
 $("#Date").datepicker({ minDate: new Date() });
```

but I can still select a date in the past.

Comment: Both of your examples should work fine. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Can you post an example on jsFiddle? Here's one of your second case working: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gxAcv/

Comment: Have you tried putting your javascript code through something like JSLint to ensure its not a typo or minor syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

aparently this is the way

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
```

remove the quotes from the 0

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried using the [mindate and maxdate parameters](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max)?

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5arx/s6WQJ/1/).

Take a [look at the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate) and have a play with it.

Comment: The OP wants the user to be able to select a date in the future (including today), not 10 days before. -1

Comment: Well he's very welcome to play with the fiddle to experiment and get what he wants ...  that's more than any of the other (non-downvoted) responses offer...

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gxAcv/) is an ideal jsfiddle, working as it is expected...

Comment: flagged for offensive language.

Comment: As you can plainly see, OP is already using the `minDate` option.

Comment: I think the OP ought to post his/her code. Its almost certainly a typo that's breaking it ...